# What could stop Array.prototype.filter() from running in greasemonkey script that runs fine in console

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Here is the code:

```
function fil(val) {
  console.log('fil'); // never written to console when run in greasemonkey
  return true;
}
var temp = unsafeWindow.someobject;
console.log(temp); // looks fine
temp.filter(fil); // never happens in greasemonkey
```

If I run the very same code (without unsafeWindow of course) on the same object in the firebug console it outputs just fine. What could be the reason?

Edit to clarify: when run in greasemonkey the string 'fil' never is written to the console which shows that fil() is never called. Also if I do something like `console.log(temp.filter(fil));` I never get to see a result from that in the console when the code runs from greasemonkey. (although I know it should because the line above tells me `temp` exists and the code runs up to that point.

Comment: What do you mean by "it outputs just fine" ? That you see the filtered array? The firebug console will show you the result of a function call for convenience, but that is not standard behaviour and while your code might work fine in greasemonkey if you don't explicitely ask for an output you won't have any.

Comment: console.log('fil') is asking for output? "outputs just fine" means I get to see the string 'fil' in the console (multiple times)

Comment: Oh nevermind, I overlooked your filter function and thought you were expecting the filtered array to be output. I don't really know then, sorry.

Comment: Anyway you should be using Array.prototype.apply instead of filter in this kind of case. Maybe this would solve your problem? - of course if you actually intend to filter the array and are just testing with this mock function, that solution is useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, in Firefox 45 and Greasemonkey 3.7, this code works fine:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Array.prototype.filter() test
// @namespace   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675675/
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675675/*
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function fil(val) {
  console.log('fil'); // never written to console when run in greasemonkey
  return true;
}
var temp = unsafeWindow.allowedHosts;
console.log(temp); // looks fine
temp.filter(fil); // never happens in greasemonkey
```

And outputs:

```
Array [ "stackoverflow.com", "serverfault.com" ]
fil
fil
```

But changing `none` to, for example, `GM_getValue` in line:

```
// @grant       none
```

Outputs only:

```
Array [ "stackoverflow.com", "serverfault.com" ]
```

This is because passing to [`@grant`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) any value other than `none` enables the sandbox, and from what I can see, the wrapped objects don't support methods that take callback functions as arguments.

You may be able to replace some `GM_*` privileges with the compatibility layer that you can find in the link above. Then you could disable the sandbox by setting `@grant none` and you're all set.

However, if you need the original functions, you could use `[].filter.call(temp, fil)` instead of `temp.filter(fil)`, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: `[].filter.call(temp, fil);` works for me. That's probably what [Aaron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1678362/aaron) meant [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33675675/1529630#comment55125157_33675675).